# laravel 5 Выборка из бд по клику на кнопку

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть таблица в MySql(id, name, price) из которой нужно вывести данные.

```
//Контроллер
public function index()
{          
    $products = Product::all();            
    return view('home', ['products' => $products]);    
}
//Представление
<div class="products">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
        <p>{{$product->price}}</p>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Данный код будет отображать выборку при загрузке страницы, можно ли сделать выполнение данной выборки из бд по клику на кнопку. И также по клику на другую кнопку удалять.
Я конечно могу скрыть данный цикл через "display:none" и потом в JS менять значение, но мне кажется это немного неправильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это просто делается через `jQuery` и `Ajax` запрос.
Изначально вы ничего не выводите на странице как и хотели, покажу простой пример, а вы уже доделывайте его.

Контроллер:

```
public function index()
{          
    return view('home');    
}

public function getProducts()
{
    $products = Product::all();            

    return response()->json([
        'ok' => true,
        'view' => view('products', compact('products'))->render()
    ]);
}
```

В роутах прописать новое правило:

```
Route::post('get-products', 'AppController@getProducts'); //Замените на свой
```

Файл представление `home.blade.php`:

```
<a href="#" class="load">Load</a>
<div class="products"></div>
<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '.load', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.post('/get-products', function(response) {
                if (response.ok == 'true') {
                    $('.products').html(response.view);
                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('.products').html('');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Файл представление для вывода товаров `products.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    <h2>{{$product->name}}</h2>
    <p>{{$product->price}}</p>
@endforeach
```

При загрузке страницы нет ничего, при нажатии на "Load" пошел Ajax запрос и подставил список продуктов, на кнопку "Remove" очистил список продуктов.

Comment: при попытке вызова .load выдает в консоле ошибку 404(POST http://localhost/get-products 404 (Not Found)). В роутах все прописал

Comment: php artisan route:list проверьте, возможно не там прописали

Comment: да нет, все правильно он отображается в роутах

Comment: вот все роуты
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::post('/', 'HomeController@store');
Route::post('get-products', 'HomeController@getProducts');

Comment: Напишите свой роут любой ли ж бы он работал и замените в коде.